# Convert a black & white image to white & transparent

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a black and white System.Drawing.Bitmap being passed from a 3rd party SDK, that I want to convert from black on white to white on transparent... i.e. make all the black pixels white, and all the white pixels transparent.

Do I have to iterate over every pixel, check the color and change it accordingly? How do I go about this?

Comment: If this is a 24bit bmp, for the transparent part, you can use bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White).  For converting black to white, you might need to iterate over it.  Look at how to get the byte[] from the image, and iterate over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a paletted image (as it should be, given that it's a BW image) you could replace black with transparent inside the palette of the bitmap (`Palette` property of `Bitmap`, edit its `Entries` property).